# Bandwidth in html 5 audio player

Tags: html

I am using a html 5 audio player on a web site to play an mp3 file.
The mp3 file is not located on my server, but on another site.

Will playing this mp3 file at all involve traffic through my server, or will the traffic go directly from the mp3 file server to the web browser on the users pc?

Comment: You have to be careful when embedding 3rd party content. First, you have to make certain you are even allowed to use the content for your own web site and secondly, even if you are, you are responsible for any damage done to users of your site by the 3rd party content, unless you state otherwise in your sites user agreement and clearly mark the 3rd party content as such.

Comment: Quite clear about that! I know the site the data comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see from the Azure admin console that now traffic is directed through my web server when playing audio in html 5, when the audio is located on a separate server.